# Does HTML has default anchors for the begin and end of the document?

Tags: html

I want to have a "Go Top" button at the bottom of my page. I don't want to use JavaScript to scroll up (what if the browser doesn't support JavaScript?). Anyone have a good idea? Thanks ahead!

Comment: Add an anchor to the top and bottom of your page...

Answer (score 2):

The URL `#` refers to the start of the document, as per URL specifications. There is no corresponding construct for the end of a document, and it would hardly make sense to jump to the end, as there is nothing to be seen after it; rather, you might wish to link to some element at the end of a document; use a normal `id` attribute for that.

[“Back to top” links are generally useless or worse](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/totop.html). But if you really want to use them, you can use just

```
<a href="#">Start of page</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `id` on `body` element

```
<body id="scroll_here">
```

And than use an anchor tag like

```
<a href="#scroll_here">Scroll to top</a>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7N348/) (Scroll down for top button)

---

It is not necessary to call an `id` on `body` element, you can also place an empty `span` or `div` element following `<body>` tag at the top, with the same `id` and it will work for you.

Comment: So I've got to define an id for every page (static page)? I think if there were some built-in ids representing the begin and end of the document or something else, the coding would be simpler.

Comment: @VikyLeaf yes you need to define `id` for each static page, else you will have to opt for jQuery or JS solution